# How do you rebut the Argument from Ignorance?

Tags: argumentation, occams-razor

Often when conspiracy theorists are told there's no evidence for their claims, they'll respond that "there's no evidence that my claim is untrue", falling back on the [argument from ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance). A priori I would expect the burden of proof to fall on the person who is making a positive claim, one that requires action, or alternatively that most deviates from Occam's razor. Is that not an accepted principle of logic? If not, how can any argument be settled? In the JFK assassination, for example, one could never prove that there *wasn't* a shooter on the grassy knoll. The only thing that can be proven with certainty is that there *was* a shooter in the School Book Depository. From a mathematical standpoint, the set of things that one would need to prove did not happen is infinite.

More broadly, how do you refute the argument of ignorance?

Comment: It isn't clear that "conspiracy theorists" are interested in rationality, logic, or sound argumentation. In other words, not even David Hasselhoff can save them all.

Comment: Why do you expect conspiracy theorists to follow accepted principles of logic (or rather rules of evidence)? There is no point to refuting rationally those who choose not to be rational. If you are looking for an effective rhetorical response, something like this would do:"there's no evidence that desks and chairs do not disappear behind our backs, or that the sky is  not filled with invisible unicorns either, so by your logic that's what we should believe".

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to refute that kind of argument because otherwise the discussion devolves and you can't possibly convince them of believing the truth, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: In logic and argumentation, and science, its an axiom that -  proof lies in the assertion - never in the negation. You prove something to be true, you never prove something to be untrue.

Comment: The flaw in this line of reasoning that can be pointed out to a neutral (and rational) third person is just what you described. As an old Italian proverb goes, "one fool can ask more questions than seven wise men can answer". A fool can think up more speculations as well. To entertain a speculation we need a *positive reason* to do so first, or we will drown in idle speculations. It can be positive evidence to the effect, or lack of alternative explanations to a puzzling event. But extraordinary conspiracy claims require extraordinary evidence, and/or ruling out all ordinary explanations.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: It is good to have a quick rejoinder, such as the one below. But conspiracy theorists I've known can actually be quite rational and coherent, even well versed in philosophy. They can always adjust the hypothesis, etc. in what I believe is a version of Quine's web of belief. And they tend to reverse Hume in equating conjunction with causation. In the end you have to appeal to pragmatic arguments about consensus and traditional standards of evidence. One flaw is that their skepticism is usually inconsistent and may accept an "authority" like the Times or Medicine on some points and not others.

Comment: I think this question implicitly presupposes that there is a conclusive rational argument against JFK conspiracy theories, rather than such conspiracies being essentially valid hypotheses. The real issue at stake tends to be trust in authority, or social trust more broadly, and one's judgment about what scale and complexity of conspiracy could exist in our society before it fell apart under its own weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual rejection is the principle of [falsifiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability), also known as the verification principle. It demands that for any statement to mean anything, it must be possible to test it for truth or falsehood. Untestable statements are meaningless, they are "not even wrong".

This principle pretty much defines the logical positivist school of philosophy, which is debunked simply by asking how the principle itself can be tested, but it remains fundamental to the philosophy of science. That is, if a statement is not (in principle) falsifiable, then it is not an objective statement about the physical world.

My usual rebuttal is that "You cannot prove that the Flying Spaghetti Monster* does not exist". The unspoken *reductio ad absurdum* is a pretty effective showstopper.

* See [Pastafarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastafarianism)

Comment: Yes, that's good. Since a certain White House Chief of Staff has been deploying such arguments lately, it is good to have a quick rejoinder! Sometimes you just have to forego logic an opt for rhetoric.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats Statements about monopoles are falsifiable, statements about the FSM are not. Falsifiability is the underlying reason we reject the argument from ignorance. Perhaps I should add something to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"In the JFK assassination, for example, one could never prove that there wasn't a shooter on the grassy knoll."

Nor does one need to. The conspiracy theorist has a positive claim that there was a second shooter, and the burden to prove it.

What you describe is in fact a very lazy strategy used by  deniers: they pretend that because they just say that something is not or was never the case, it's up to their opponent to have the burden of proof. They can just lazily poke holes in all your facts, which is easy using the hypercritical method ("some of your testimonies are inconsistent with each other! FAKE!" And "all your testimonies are perfectly consistent with each other. It's improbable and obviously a forgery! FAKE!")

The thing is, deniers are in fact making the very positive claim that a huge conspiracy exists to create the masquerade they are denying. Globe deniers have to assert that all astronomers, space agencies, air flight companies and all of their personal, transoceanic boat pilots, bridge architects and builders, are in on the conspiracy to pretend they do their work as if the earth was a globe when they in fact know it is flat. Such a huge concerted effort has to leave some kind of paper trail. At least a testimony from a whistleblower among the hundreds of thousands of conspiracy member. One single piece of such evidence would do more for their case than all the denying in the world. Yet, they consistently fail to provide it.

I found this line of reasoning extremely useful with holocaust deniers. I think it can be applied to most denial type of conspiracy theory.

Comment: Conspiracists DO point to one or two pieces of evidence -- often from suspect sources, or requiring twisted interpretation to become "evidence", but your rhetorical assumption that they are operating evidence-free, is false, and will therefore be entirely ineffective with them.

Comment: It is true that they can provide flimsy evidence, like a quote mine or irrelevant symbols. But those can be easily dismissed. Nonetheless, I should have specified *solid* evidence.

Comment: As soon as you agree to that, then the conversation has to change, to a discussion about evidence quality, source reliability, and the method by which poorly supported speculations are dismissed.  And the conspiricists will disagree with your standards about evidence quality, and source reliability.

Comment: Well, at least if I can bring them to clarify their poor standard of evidence, I can then put their nose in their own s**t. Arguably, for the worst cases of nut job it won't be enough. But nothing will ever be enough for those. At least I can make them look for what they are to the eyes of the bystanders. It works.

Comment: Yes, that is what I try to do as well.  It is -- not very effective, in my experience.

Comment: An example -- "skeptics" of parapsych phenomena like to cite the Skeptic web sites, organizations, and experts.  When I point out to them the history of dishonesty that Amazing Randi, for example, has - I have been told that his history of uncovering other frauds is sufficient excuse for his net positive contributions.  When I note that CSICOP engaged in data fraud, and personal smears of actual researchers, from its outset, and purged is own whistleblowers, and installing the fraudsters in their steering committee and presidency instead - they still will believe CSICOP over real researchers

Comment: And Alex Jones still has an audience. It might be impossible to turn someone to reason in one conversation, or ever. Ego is involved too, some people will never concede even if they feel you are right. Sometimes you plant the seed and they come back later with a revised position. Sometimes nothing will work. Most of the time, such a discution is beneficial not to the other participant, but to other people who read or ear it.

Comment: I too have had your negative view of deniers.  Truthers, anti-Vax, AGW denial, all have a very anti-reasoning reputation.  But I see the same issues when discussing with anti-parapsych skeptics, who tend otherwise to be informed, and reasonable people.  The tendency to believe what we want to believe, and skew judgement on sources and their reasoning, is not limited to the more "out there" conspiracists.  Even the most apparently "reasonable" of people can suffer from the same sorts of myside bias.  And very few people are willing to dig into the philosophy of science far enough to settle this

Comment: This leads me to try to be more charitable with the more out there conspiracists.  AND to feel frustration about being able to convince any of them.

Comment: I agree that poor reasoning can be found to support any position, even a valid one. Yet I think the main difference between psychic deniers and holocaust deniers/flat earthers etc. is in the nature of the positive claim their position implies: holocaust deniers can only make sense of the evidence for the holocaust by positing a humongous, international conspiracy involving millions of people for decades. Psychic deniers only have to posit a psychic is either a fraud or deluded about their own power. The former claim is pretty extraordinary, requiring extraordinary evidence, the later is not.

Comment: That is the rationalization that parapsych deniers fall back on.  Susan Blackmore noted in her autobiography she will never believe any evidence supporting parapsych, because she considers "cheating" by researchers to be more plausible than that parapsych is real.  This is explicitly to reject the POSSIBILITY of refutability for the denier POV -- IE rejection of empiricism, science, and any evidence -- while asserting a dogma instead.  Pointing this out to parapsych deniers -- is generally useless, as with all deniers.  Note the rhetorical use of "extraordinary" leads to anti-science.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say an unproven assertion is true just because no one can prove it's false. A good example comes from Mathematics: there are statements that have remained unproven for more than 100 years but you won't hear any mathematician say: "well, since no one has proven them true, they must be false". In those cases both the statement and its negation remain undecided. The same is true in any other field of knowledge.